# how can I define multiples methods in a class to call them from a component

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble calling any method from my `serviceProvider` `class`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React  from 'react';
export class ServiceProvider {
 hello(){

    alert("hi");
 }
 goodBye(){
    alert("bye")
 }

}
```

Getting my methods

```
import { ServiceProvider } from "./providers/services"

function App() {

  {this.ServiceProvider.hello()}   //this line

   return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
      <Route exact path="/principal" component={Principal} />
      <Route exact path="/secondary" component={Secondary} />
      <Route  component={Notfound} />
     </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
   );
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: Is `"./providers/services"` a directory, in which contains a file called `ServiceProvider.js`?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also either remove the `{ }` from the `ServiceProvider.hello()` call or move it inside the JSX part

Comment: Won't `this` be undefined as you are not calling it from within a class component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can access the functions that way. I rewrote `ServiceProvider` to look like this.

```
 import React  from 'react';
 const ServiceProvider = {
     hello: function(){
        alert("hi");
     }, 
     goodBye: function(){
         alert("bye")
     }

  };

  export default ServiceProvider;
```

Then change `import { ServiceProvider } from "./providers/services"` to `import ServiceProvider from "./providers/services/ServiceProvider";` if the directory contains a `ServiceProvider.js` file.

If you're using `.jsx` syntax you can keep it as `import { ServiceProvider } from "./providers/services"` just make sure the filename is `index.jsx` and it's in `./providers/services`